# Fefferman Metrics

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Is there any reference for studying the Fefferman metrics except his original paper? It would be appreciated if somebody introduce a source for knowing  that.

Comment: What did you try? Google? Bing?

Comment: I tried google espacialy google books.

Answer (score 1):

This is treated in the book *[Differential Geometry and Analysis on CR Manifolds](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/0-8176-4483-0)* by Sorin Dragomir and Giuseppe Tomassini.